# Just another confusion on Fermi level and Fermi energy

Tags: solid-state-physics, definition, chemical-potential, fermi-energy

I've heard it so many times:

> "At 0 K Fermi energy and Fermi level are the same."
>
> "The Fermi level for an intrinsic semiconductor lies at the middle of
>   the band gap."

And the definition of the Fermi energy is

> The highest level of energy up to which electrons are filled.

Now my confusion is if Fermi energy is an energy state filled by electron how can it (Fermi energy=Fermi level at 0K) lie in the band gap (gap means there is no energy state that can be occupied by electron)?

Comment: As there is no state available at the fermi energy, in energy level diagram, so the probability that fermi level will be occupied doesn't make any sense. At 0 K valance band is filled upto its max energy level.

Comment: You may want to look at my answer to another question here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/549647/247642

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding the Fermi level and the Fermi-Dirac distribution](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/549577/)