# Fermi level of a semiconductor

Tags: statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

When calculating the career concentrations in the conduction band of a intrinsic semiconductor we consider the integral $\int_{E_c}^\infty g_C(E)f_{FD}(E,T)dE$ where $g_c$ is the density of states in conduction band and $f_{FD}$ is the Fermi-Dirac distribution.
$$f_{FD}=\frac1{1+e^{(E-E_F)/k_BT}}$$
where $E_F$ is the intrinsic fermi level. I have a problem that, does the intrinsic fermi level $E_F$ depend on temperature ?

Comment: I suggest reading this for better understanding: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/549647/247642

Answer (score 0):

The Fermi energy $E_F$ is defined as the chemical potential $\mu$ at $T=0\,$K, so it doesn't depend on the temperature.

Comment: Techncially correct, but note that *Fermi energy* and *Fermi level* are not the same thing: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/549647/247642

Comment: And the Fermi level and the chemical potential are not the same thing.